# Is it safe to rm -rf an untrusted directory?

Tags: linux, deletion, directory-traversal

There are a lot of linking tools(symlinks, hard links, mount, etc.) available. Suppose a disgruntled employee gets the idea that he's going to hide a link to the root directory or some mission-critical directory, so that a lazy sysadmin who runs "rm -rf /home/joe" after he's fired ends up destroying something important.

What are the ways that Joe can cause trouble with links? Is there a configuration setting to protect the lazy sysadmin? How should a paranoid sysadmin safely delete a directory that may contain suspicious links?

Comment: Do you assume that Joe has root permissions? He could mount the drive inside his home dir, but he'd need the privileges for that. Links on the other hand wouldn't do any harm.

Comment: Sure - if it's a disgruntled employee, he's probably had plenty of chances to get temporary root access for e.g. production issues, or on a different machine that shares drives via NFS, or otherwise.

Comment: The `paranoid sysadmin` *doesn't* delete anything: the paranoid sysadmin *disables* access and *preserves* all data. (Also: multiple, automated, offsite and tested backups.)

Comment: @Arminius hardlinks would do harm; `rm -r` dives into the directory, removes all its children, and then unlinks the hardlink. The original directory would still exist, but by that point it would be empty. No, Linux does not allow hardlinked directories, but there are other unices that do. That also needs root though, so we get back to your original point...

Comment: @WouterVerhelst: FreeBSD no longer allows hard links to directory either. I think it should be a generalized feature nowadays. That means the higher risk is probably the mounting of a filesystem as suggested by Arminius.

Comment: @WoutherVerhelst Well, the [Linux] tag suggests that OP's scenario is limited to that, but I take your hint for other *nixes. Obviously, hard links could also cause trouble if the admin decides to zero out file contents before deletion.

Comment: Did you consider giving the question a slightly different title? Maybe something along the lines of "Is it safe to rm -rf an untrusted directory"?

Comment: @Arminius , your suggested title is much clearer, so I've changed it. Thanks  for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard link to directories have been brought up in comments. Nominally they cannot happen; Unix-like systems have disallowed them for a long time because they would allow the creation of loops. Since space allocation in such a filesystem is based on [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), a file being really deallocated when the last link on it disappears, a directory loop could induce a bunch of inaccessible files that are not reclaimed.

However, being disallowed does not mean that it cannot be done; only that the purported disgruntled employee would have to fiddle with the disk structure, which would entail root or physical access (root access to do it remotely; if the employee had physical access then he could simply reboot on a live CD or USB to play with the disk). In the filesystem structure, sub-directories are referenced from the parent directory, and noticing a case of the same directory being referenced from two distinct parent directories would require, in all generality, a complete vision of the whole directory tree. The kernel does *not* try to maintain such a vision since it could potentially use up more RAM than available. Thus, if the directory structures are altered to include several links to the same directory, the live system won't notice it.

`fsck` detects loops, but it does so only when it runs, i.e. only at boot time, and then only once every N reboots, for some (configurable) value of N. It *may* detect some other cases of multiple links to the same directory (without making a cycle) but I cannot vouch on that, for the same reason as explained above: to reliable detect all cases of multiple links, the complete directory tree must fit in the RAM of the detection process. Loops are easily detected with a depth-first tree walk, but acyclic non-tree structure require more resources.

But, more generally, if the bad Joe had root or root-equivalent access, and is assumed to have potentially used it with nefarious intent, then the whole machine should be touched only with prongs, and only to push it to some industrial-grade shredder.

---

Symbolic links, on the other hand, do not cause harm here. `rm` won't follow symbolic links.

Evil Joe could have mounted another partition in a sub-directory of his own home directory, but, there again, it would require root access, and we are back to the previous paragraph.

---

In general, when an employee leaves the company, the process should involve a wiping/re-imaging of his workstation or laptop. If the employee is considered capable of mischief and assumed to have indulged in active sabotage, then deletion would not be the right thing to do anyway: you want to do some forensics and keep proofs.

Comment: If I do full `fsck` first, is there any other attacks than can exists for `rm -rf untrusted-dir` or `rm -rf --one-file-system untrusted-dir`?